# Understanding Complex Form of Green's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-analysis, complex-integration, greens-theorem

I'm reviewing complex analysis for the GRE. I've never taken a course in complex analysis before, but I do know vector calculus.

I'm trying to understand the statement of the complex version of Green's theorem, which has a few symbols that I've never seen before.

$$ \oint_C F(z,\overline{z}) dz = 2i \iint_{R} \frac{\partial F}{\partial \overline{z}} dA $$

For example, what is $F(z,\overline{z})?$ How is $\partial F/\partial \overline{z}?$ defined?

Also, if there is an obvious connection to Green's theorem on a plane (the real version) I would appreciate an explanation!

Comment: Any function in $x,y$ can be written in $z,\bar z$ using $z=x+iy, \bar z=x-iy, 2x=z+\bar z, 2iy=z-\bar z$; in particular $dz=dx+idy$ so $Fdz=Fdx+iFdy$; the usual green theorem gives that the line integral in cause is the area integral of $iF_x-F_y=2i\frac{F_x+iF_y}{2}$ and the latter operator is precisely $F_{\bar z}$ by definition, so the result above is a restating of the usual green theorem